# Split string from start and end positions

Tags: c#, asp.net

C# string

```
string str =@"
'START: Store

'START: Store.Car1
  Here sampel description of car 1
'END:Store.Car1

'START: Store.Car2
  Here sampel description of car 2
'END:Store.Car2

'END: Store"
```

Here, I want to get the string content between the 'START: Store and 'END: Store. Currently, I am using the the following code to split using Start:

```
string[] newString= str.Split(new string[]{
                        "'START:"
                    }, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

How to split using start and end positions? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Curious, what data format is that?

Comment: It is not clear. What is the expected result ? Only the 2 lines "Here..." or all the content withing the main START/END block ?

Answer (score 4):

```
string str =@"
'START: Store

'START: Store.Car1


Here sampel description of car 1
'END:Store.Car1

'START: Store.Car2
  Here sampel description of car 2
'END:Store.Car2

'END: Store";

var startString: = "'START: Store";
var startIndex = str.IndexOf(startString) + startString.Length;
var endIndex = str.LastIndexOf("'END: Store");
var concatedString = str.Substring(startIndex, endIndex - startIndex);
```